# How to define property in one component and pass to other component in reactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

> I have a parent component and a child component, I want to pass
>   property from Parent to Child by using {...this.props}, I dont want
>   any action or reducer in the picture,Is it possible to do this?

My Child Component is like this:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

 class SampleChild extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
   }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>This is Parent</div>
          )
         }
  }

 SampleChild.propTypes={
        Header:React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
 }
 export default SampleChild
```

My Parent Component is like this:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class SampleParent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
      return(
          <div><SampleChild {...this.props}/></div>
      )
  }
}
export default SampleParent
```

Now how can I pass the Header Property from the SampleParent Component to SampleChild?.Please assist me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your parent/child relation, I don't see the parent including the child, only the child including the parent which is the exact opposite. Is that correct?

Comment: Your child is rendering the parent, which is contrary to what logic dictates. Please clarify your question. In react you pass properties via attributes, like: `<Component property={value} />`, dont know if that helps you.

Comment: @VincasStonys I have update my question.Please assist me how can I pass the Header Property from Parent Component to child component by using {...this.props}

Comment: Really hard to understand you @jack, make an effort to clarify your question please.

Comment: any reason why you need to use `{...this.props}`? Are there any other props you need from the parent component other than the Header?

Comment: @jpdelatorre yes you are correct .In real time scenario we have many property that we need to pass to childComponent, here I have asked only sample example.My question is very simple, Can we define the property in Parent Component and pass to child component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<SampleParent Header="Hello from Parent" />
```

Will do the trick for you since you're spreading all props coming from `SampleParent` to `SampleChild` you need to make sure that the `SampleParent` just receives it as a prop if it's dynamic.

If it's a static prop you can define it in `defaultProps` for the `SampleParent` and you'll always pass the same string.

```
SampleParent.defaultProps = {
   Header: 'Hello from Parent'
}
```

Comment: I am passing the property as <SampleChild {...this.props}/>, but your answer is not matching with my requirement, Please update it. And also I donot want to pass directly as you did <SampeParent Header="bla bla"/>

Comment: @jack The issue here is that you're not setting the `Header` prop in the `SampleParent` component and thus it will not be passed onto the `SampleChild` component.

Comment: that's what I want to know how to define and pass to child component?

Comment: I do not understand your problem then, @HenrikAndersson has answered your question the way you asked it. Do you want to pass it as children? Do you want to dynamically generate the Header? It's not clear at all from your question. If you want it dynamically, just pass the variable value: `<SampleParent Header={header} />` and it will be available on `this.props.Header` on parent component

Comment: @HenrikAndersson SampleParent.defaultProps ={Header:'hello'} solved my problem, I was looking for the static prop to define.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to pass "all" props from parent to child, you can do it this way.

From the component that is rendering the SampleParent ...

```
<SampleParent />
```

The SampleParent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import SampleChild from './SampleChild';

class SampleParent extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <SampleChild {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

SampleParent.defaultProps = {
  Header: "Header from parent"
}

export default SampleParent;
```

The SampleChild component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class SampleChild extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>This is the Header passed from parent:</div>
        {this.props.Header}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

SampleChild.propTypes = {
  Header: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

export default SampleChild;
```

Comment: I already told that I dont want to use like this :- <SampleParent Header="Header from Parent" />, Is there any way that I can define the Header inside by SampleParent Component and pass it to the SampleChild.

Comment: Yes you can. You can use defaultProps. I have edited this in the post. Just realized this was already answered!